# Installing dotnet 6 preview 6 RPM packages alongside version 5 packages

Tags: .net, rpm, .net-5, .net-6.0

I downloaded and ran the `install-dotnet-preview.sh` provided by Microsoft (not sure if I'm allowed to provide a link for it?). Part of it downloads the RPM packages for dotnet 6. When it gets to installing them, it fails with the following error:

```
package netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-5.0.205-1.fc34.x86_64 (which is newer than netstandard-targeting-pack-2.1-2.1.0-1.x86_64) is already installed
```

I know I can force the installation, but I'm worried it might interfere with version 5.

Is there a way to multiple versions of the same RPM packages, or is there another recommended way to install dotnet RPM packages alongside the existing, dotnet 5 specific ones?

Comment: Can you point me to where I can find `install-dotnet-preview.sh`?

Answer (score 2):

Mixing .NET installations from multiple providers (Fedora and Microsoft) is a bad idea. The packages can install to different locations and are known to break: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup

If you want to use the preview packages from Microsoft, I suggest using the non-preview packages from them too. That's option 3 at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-package-mixup#solutions, if you are using their RPM packages. That solution looks like this, but I am not sure if this works out of the box for `install-dotnet-preview.sh`:

```sh
echo 'priority=50' | sudo tee -a /etc/yum.repos.d/microsoft-prod.repo
sudo dnf remove 'dotnet*' 'aspnet*' 'netstandard*'
sudo dnf install dotnet-sdk-5.0
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into it. I will try it out and get back to you.